# Recursive setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Is it possible to run this "indefinitely", without causing stack overflow or running out of memory?

```
function eternal(){
    var time = recalculateTime();
    doSomething();
    setTimeout(eternal,time);
}

setTimeout(eternal,200000);
```

I'm not using setInterval, because the triggering time is variable.

Comment: Your code should work fine as is without running out of memory. Are you having trouble with it?

Comment: No, it's because in another language such as C# or Java, something like this will eventually produce a stack overflow exception, because it will be a recursive call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not actually a recursive call because the first invocation of `eternal()` has actually finished before the `setTimeout()` calls the next one.  So, it's not technically recursion and does not build up the stack over time.  It can run forever without any buildup and this is a perfectly fine way to keep something running over and over.

In response to one of your comments, javascript is not multi-threaded so it does not create multiple threads for timers.  Each timer event that fires just puts an event into the event queue and if no JS is running at the time, that event is triggered (thus calling the callback function).  If JS is running at the time, the JS engine waits until the currently executing JS finishes and then services the next event in the event queue  (thus calling the callback).

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine. Once `setTimeout` runs it will return from the `eternal` function before it's calls it again.

Comment: Doesn't it will create a cascade of threads, every one waiting their childrens to finish? Just wondering, I'm not very familiar with the async part of javascript.

Comment: As I mention, and jfriend00 says in his answer, the `eternal` method finishes and returns prior to the next invocation. So it's not actually recursive.